# How to return form the web(iOS) back to the app?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, appery.io

I am using an online builder for my app(ApperyDotIo, JQM framework). My application works fine with one exception. I have an in-app link to my website. The link in the iOS app, the link takes me to the page but since the iPhone doesn't have a "back" button I can't go back to the app. Looks like you have to close the app and then reopen it to get back into the app.

I tried to set the link to not open in the same window and vice versa.

Any easy work around?

Links and back buttons in Android apps work fine.

Thank you

Comment: "*the iPhone doesn't have a "back" button*" It's not clear to what you're referring in this statement. When one app causes a switch to another, the app name and a left arrow indicator appear in the upper-left of the OS interface to allow the user to switch back to the previous app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using the inAppBrowser: https://docs.appery.io/docs/cordova-jquerymobile-inappbrowser

It will allow you to open the website in the child window of the application (with the "close" button) or in the native browser, without opening the website as application page.